# ModX - Output depending on id of the resousce and parent id

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm trying to output certain meta description depending on resource ID and parent ID using ModX Revo.

The problem is that Modx filters only can operate **only one** special tag (or id, or parent id, or something else), for ex.

```
[[*id:is=`331`:then=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]] — Page [[+page]]" />`:else=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]]" />`]]
```

In this case tag is **ID**. In my situation I need to add to this condition one more statement, it must work like:

- if [[*id]] is 331 then...
- else if [[*parent]] is 321 then..
- else...

How can I do this without creating templates or chunks?
I tried some variants:

This just doesn't work

```
[[*id:is=`331`:then=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]] — Page [[+page]]" />`:else=`[[*parent:is=`321`:then=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]] - News Page" />`:else=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]]" />`]]]]
```

OR

This on the 331st resource outputs two descriptions

```
[[*id:is=`331`:then=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]] — Page [[+page]]" />`:else=``]] 
[[*parent:is=`321`:then=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]] - News Page" />`:else=`<meta name="description" content="[[*description]]" />`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at pdoField or one of the other pdoTools snippets. There are already built in parameters for doing the kind of filtering and conditionals you seem to need.
[pdoField DOCS](http://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdofield)

Make sure to look at the general pdoTools properties as well as those that are specific to pdoField.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to wind up with duplicate descriptions, not great for SEO & probably better ways to get where you want. But that was not the question.

Your best bet is to write a quick snippet, where you want to output the meta tag:

```
[[!getMeta? &resourceid='[[*id]]' ]]
```

in your getMeta snippet:

```
<?php

$id = isset($scriptProperties('resourceid')) ? $scriptProperties('resourceid') : FALSE

if(!$id){ return; }

$output = '';

if($modx->getParent($id,1,'id') == 321){

     $output = '...your meta tag for the funny parent';

}else{

     if($id == 331){
          $output = '...your meta tag...';
     }else{
          $output = '...your alternate meta tag...';
     }

}

echo $output;

return;
```

Something along those lines. 
- you should be creating chunks to output any HTML OR you can store the chunk in a property set.

Comment: Thanks! Can I just write `$output = '<meta...>';? Also, when I added this snippet to my template, site became non-working. What can be wrong?